# Binom.test error in R: " formal argument "p" matched by multiple actual arguments"

Tags: r, bernoulli-distribution

I'm running a binom.test on the data set UCBAdmissions (comes with R) and am stuck on an error message.

**About the data:**

```
> str(UCBAdmissions)
table [1:2, 1:2, 1:6] 512 313 89 19 353 207 17 8 120 205 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
..$ Admit : chr [1:2] "Admitted" "Rejected"
    ..$ Gender: chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
..$ Dept  : chr [1:6] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

*Number of females: 1835

*Number of femaled Admitted: 557

*Number of males: 2691

*Number of males Admitted: 1198

**I'm trying to answer this question:**

"Do you think there was gender discrimination?"

**It's a Bernoulli distribution so I am using the binom.test, however I get an error message that I can't make sense of:**

```
no.w <- sum(UCBAdmissions[1,2,])
no.acc.w <- sum(UCBAdmissions[1,2,])
binom.test(no.acc.w,no.w, p = .304, c="two-sided", p=.95)
Error in binom.test(no.acc.w, no.w, p = 0.304, c = "two-sided", p = 0.95) : 
formal argument "p" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

In advance, thanks for poking holes in this and pointing me in the right direction.

Jen

Comment: In R 2.15.2, `binom.test(no.acc.w,no.w, p = .304, alternative="two.sided", conf.level=.95)` works. The error message is because you have two arguments, both named `p`.

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what the problem is - you defined `p` twice in the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You set two different values for p in the arguments of the fonction binom.test.
Maybe you wanted to write

```
binom.test(no.acc.w,no.w, p = 0.304, c="two-sided", conf.level=0.95)
```

You can find the description of this function on this site : http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/binom.test.html